# Testing whether certain elements are visible or not

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner

How do I find out if an element is visible or hidden in testacular (jasmine)?

My DOM looks like:

```
<div class="span5 value-entry">
    <input type="text" ng-model="query.value" placeholder="Enter value" class="input-large" ng-show="genericInput(criteria.attribute)">
    <select ng-model="query.value" ng-options="entry for entry in filteredValue(criteria.attribute)" class="input-medium" ng-show="!genericInput(criteria.attribute)">
        <option value="">-- Select Value --</option>.
    </select>
</div>
```

Either the select is shown or the input box, but not both. I wish to check which element is visible (based on some other criteria), but I can't seem to figure out how to get the code working. I have written the following code:

```
expect(element('.value-entry input').is(':visible')).toBe(true);
```

But I get an error:

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'is'
```

How do I check if the input is visible and the select is hidden at the same time (and vice versa)?

**EDIT :** I wish to add here that this is an end to end test

Comment: See also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16703276/angular-watch-for-ngshow-nghide-changes-in-ancestors-that-affect-child-dom-ele for a solution that also considers the ancestors visibility

Answer (score 54, accepted):

This behavior has changed in Angular 1.2 because of `ng-animate`.

The code for `ngShow` is:

```
var ngShowDirective = ['$animate', function($animate) {
  return function(scope, element, attr) {
    scope.$watch(attr.ngShow, function ngShowWatchAction(value){
      $animate[toBoolean(value) ? 'removeClass' : 'addClass'](element, 'ng-hide');
    });
  };
}];
```

Which means that it will add/remove class `ng-hide` to hide/show the element.

Thus, as an example, the right way to test if the element is hidden would be:

```
expect(element.find('.value-entry input').hasClass('ng-hide')).toBe(true);
```

Comment: This should be the new answer, since things have changed in how elements are hidden. However, using the .hasClass() method might be a little easier on the eyes.

Comment: There is a `hasClass()` in Jasmine?

Comment: @georgiosd: angular.element has a _hasClass_ method

Comment: @null Updated my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 14):

You were close. However, here is how you should test visibility:

```
expect(element('#some-id:visible').count()).toBe(1);
```

Comment: **Heads up!** This will only work if you have jQuery included, otherwise this will not work throwing an error similar to: `Looking up elements via selectors is not supported by jqLite!` Check here for more details: http://embed.plnkr.co/g5ZdYpLrKWR1u8R0GOB9/ (don't forget to open the console).

Answer (score 6):

## Visibility Test

By default, display is set to `inline` for input, and `inline-block` for select. Therefore, you can determine if either are currently shown by testing for the existence of the default CSS property.

```
expect(element('.value-entry input').css('display')).toBe('inline');
expect(element('.value-entry select').css('display')).toBe('inline-block');
```

To check if either are hidden, replace `inline` and `inline-block` with a check for `none`, which is how [ngShow](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angShow) hides an element.

```
expect(element('.value-entry input').css('display')).toBe('none');
expect(element('.value-entry select').css('display')).toBe('none');
```

Comment: This test is tied closely to the implementation of ng-show which adds brittleness.  Using the selector suggested by 'Shadowedged' to identify visible elements defers the visibility test logic and keeps your tests further away from implementation.

Comment: This makes perfect sense, however, I keep getting element is not a function in a type error