# Angular - Watch for ngShow/ngHide Changes in Ancestors that Affect Child DOM Element's Visibility

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am a DOM element (bound to, say, a table).  I am the downstream child of an ngShow-based tabs control.  I live on the second tab.  When the page is rendered, I exist but I am not really visible yet.

I would like to somehow be notified when I become visible through my not-immediate parent, when its ngShow expression becomes true.

Is this possible?  I would like to avoid adding code anywhere outside myself - for example, I'd rather not add code in a tab-changed event somewhere.  I'd rather have a way to register to find out when, via changes in outermost containers that are bound via ngShow/ngHide, my visibility changes.  Can this be done?

Comment: This is possible. Have you tried using a `$watch`?

Comment: $watch requires something specific to watch on a scope somewhere, right?  I'm not sure what I would plug into it.

Comment: If you have access to whatever data is triggering the ngShow/ngHide, you could put a $watch on that and trigger the behavior when it changes.  If you are in some kind of isolation scope (or the ngShow/ngHide variable is a primitive and won't properly update in the child scope(s)) and you don't want/know how many levels up to reach through your scopes parent, then you may need to try something like what I suggested below.

Answer (score 21):

Since you have a scope available in the directive, you could use this to watch for changes in visibility:

```
scope.$watch(function() { return element.is(':visible') }, function() {
  // Do whatever should happen when the visibility changes
});
```

This avoids polling the visibility, which could be a performance hit. Of course, this assumes that the scope is applied by whatever causes the visibility to change. I've tried it in my own directive, but not related to ngShow/ngHide.

Credit where credit is due: this was originally proposed (not by me) here: 
https://groups.google.com/d/msg/angular/w7Gxa5M_17M/koYCZnsobawJ

**EDIT 2014-02-24**
Revisiting this answer a few months laters, I have noticed that this works but will slow down your digest cycle quite a bit. Best practice is to not use expensive functions such as this for dirty checking. Use with caution!

Comment: This solution can not be applied for elements that are replaced by select2.

Answer (score 8):

The best way I found:

```
link: function (scope, element, attr) {
    attr.$observe('ngShow', function (expr) {
        scope.$watch(function () {
            return $parse(expr)(scope);
        }, function (value) {
            console.log(value)
        })
    });
}
```

Good Luck!

Comment: Why not just scope.$watch(expr, function(value){...}) ?

Answer (score 4):

I did this with a directive:

Elemement:

```
<test-directive ng-show="showMe" show-model="showMe"></test-directive>
```

Directive:

```
app.directive('testDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            showModel: "=?",
        },
        controller: function($scope) {
            if (angular.isDefined($scope.showModel)) {
                $scope.$watch('showModel', function(newValue, oldValue) {
                    // Do stuff
                });
            }
        }
     }
});
```

So the idea is to put a $watch on the same variable linked to ng-show.

Answer (score 3):

The only thing I can think to do is create a directive that loops to see if the element is visible.  Something like:

```
angular.module('testModule', [])
  .directive('onVisible', ['$timeout', function($timeout) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {
        onVisible: '&'
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var checkVisibility = function() {
              if (element.is(':visible')) {
                scope.onVisible();
              } else {
                $timeout(checkVisibility, 100);
              }
            };
        $timeout(checkVisibility, 100);
      }
    };
  }]);
```

Of course, if you need it to execute every time the element becomes visible, you would also need to watch for the element transitioning back to hidden.

**Edit**: This assumes you have jQuery available.

Comment: Thank you - I ended up doing something a bit similar, but instead of polling on an interval I'm watching for $digest events (throttling to at most once per 500ms using Underscore's throttle() method) and re-checking visibility within that handler instead . . .

Comment: @blaster Yeah, that should work as long as whatever is triggering visibility is calling $apply().

Answer (score 3):

Another possible way can be using $broadcast. When your tab is selected, you can broadcast an event

`$scope.$broadcast('secondTabSelected');`

You can handle this event inside your controller and do further processing.

```
$scope.$on('secondTabSelected', function(e){
    // do something awesome.
})
```

This will notify you each time the tab is visible. For executing it only once, you can do

```
var firstTimeSelected = false;
$scope.$on('secondTabSelected', function(e){
    if(firstTimeSelected){
        firstTimeSelected = true;
        // do something awesome
    }
})
```