# Watch for element visibility change in angulardart

Tags: scope, dart, watch, angular-dart

I have the same exact question that has already been posted for angularjs ([Angular - Watch for ngShow/ngHide Changes in Ancestors that Affect Child DOM Element's Visibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16703276/angular-watch-for-ngshow-nghide-changes-in-ancestors-that-affect-child-dom-ele)) except in my case we are using angulardart.  I cannot seem to watch a function in angulardart.  When I try to, I get an error from the expression parser stating that "{" is unexpected.  Is there a better way to do this in angulardart?  If not, how can I watch a function similar to angularjs?

I've tried the following code with no success:

```
scope.watch("() { return _element.hidden; }", (value, _) {
        print(value);
});
```

> Parser Error: Unexpected token ) at column 2 in [() { return _element.hidden; }]

```
scope.watch("(scope) { return _element.hidden; }", (value, _) {
        print(value);
});
```

> Parser Error: '{' is an unexpected token at column 9 in [(scope) { return _element.hidden; }]

We are using angular.dart 1.1.2

Comment: Without seeing your code, I am unable to help. Most likely, you have an extra (or are lacking) the `{` character, making the program look for a closure to the function. I suggest combing through your code with possibly an IDE that highlights brackets.

Comment: What angular version? Angular.dart or Angular 2 for Dart?

Comment: My question was not intended to be help fixing a syntax error.  I'd prefer to know the proper way to trigger some code based on visibility of an element (exactly like the original question, except using angulardart).  Please do not feel constrained by my attempt to follow the angularjs pattern provided by the angularjs post.  Thanks.

Comment: You could use MutationObserver, it notifies about DOM changes. See for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18927901 (there should be more examples on SO)

Comment: Thanks Günter!  This was exactly what I needed.  The MutationObserver did not trigger on my element due to it being hidden by an element further up in the dom, but I was able to traverse up the dom tree, identify that element, and observe it.  Worked like a charm.  Can you please post this as an answer so that I can accept it?  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use MutationObserver, it notifies about DOM changes. See for example [In Dart why the code below (about MutationObserver) dose not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18927901) (there should be more examples on SO)