# bxslider bx-viewport height is 0 if shown later

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, bxslider

I have an angular application in which i am using bxslider plugin.

I have created bxslider directive to call the plugin and everything was working fine till i extended the functionality.

This is the code for creating directive

```
angular.module('sbAdminApp')
.directive('bxSlider', function(){
    return{
        restrict: "A",
        require: "ngModel",
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl){
            element.ready(function(){
                $($(element[0])).bxSlider({
                    controls:false,
                    pager:true,
                    maxSlides: 1,
                    minSlides:1
                });
            })
        }
    }
})
```

This is the html

```
<div class="banner_section" ng-model="bannerSlider" bx-slider>
    <div class="slide" ng-repeat="banner in mobileBanner track by $index">
        <img ng-src="images/{{banner}}">
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller with values in array

```
angular.module('sbAdminApp')
.controller('mobileViewCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.mobileBanner = ['banner_small.png', 'banner_small.png', 'banner_small.png'];
})
```

But actually that slider div is hidden and i am showing it with `ng-show` on click of anchor because of which the height of bxslider is 0 i need to do slight resize of window to let bxslider get the required height.

I want bxslider should come correct initially when i am showing div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all you support mates. I found the answer.

I was using `ng-show` to manage when i need to show the slider because of which initially the slider was hidden and giving problem.

But now i switched to `ng-if` which is not just hiding the slider or completely removing it from DOM and insert it when i need so that `bxslider` is initialised only when shown and working completely fine.

Found the difference here : [what is the difference between ng-if and ng-show/ng-hide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19177732/what-is-the-difference-between-ng-if-and-ng-show-ng-hide)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that - Slides/images must be visible before slider gets initiate.

In your case possible solutions are -

**Either:**

1. You can reload slider after ng-show animation complete
2. Slider can be initiate after ng-show animation complete

### To reload bx slider doc -

http://bxslider.com/examples/reload-slider

http://bxslider.com/examples/reload-slider-settings

Sample code:

```
var slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
  mode: 'horizontal'
});
//Inside ng-show callback
slider.reloadSlider();
```

### Trigger event when ng-show is complete

[Call a function when ng-show is triggered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21056037/call-a-function-when-ng-show-is-triggered)

Comment: This answer showing how to perform a function after `ng-show` but in my case i have created a directive which should work after `ng-show`. How to do this??

Comment: @GauravAggarwal  Please refer - 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16703276/angular-watch-for-ngshow-nghide-changes-in-ancestors-that-affect-child-dom-ele

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21056037/call-a-function-when-ng-show-is-triggered

https://codepen.io/raduvultur/pen/Ahwne