# angular e2e tests: How can I check if an element got the focus?

Tags: angularjs, focus, karma-runner

I have an angular.js application that should set the focus to a specific element when doing something (ie, set the focus to an invalid form field to let the user correct the error).

I'm trying to test this behavior within an angular-e2e test:

```
it('should set the focus to the invalid field', function() {
  input('email').enter('foo'); // this is not a valid email address
  element(/* submit button */).click(); // try to submit the form

  // How do I do this?
  expect(element(/* email input element */)).toHaveTheFocus();
});
```

**How can I expect a certain element to (not) have the focus?** I already tried the ':focus' selector

```
expect(element('input[id="..."]:focus').count()).toBe(1);
```

but no success (inspired by [Testing whether certain elements are visible or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16022180/testing-whether-certain-elements-are-visible-or-not)).

To set the focus, I use the idea of [How to set focus on input field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14833326/how-to-set-focus-in-angularjs)

I was also writing unit tests for this and ended up using a spy on the DOM focus() function (which is, as far as I know, not possible/desireable for e2e tests).

Comment: I had same problem when trying to test setting focus on input. Try to insert testing element in DOM (but it didn't help me).

Comment: I'm using a directive that adds a tooltip to the DOM when the focus is set. So I can check if the focus is right by checking if the tooltip is right. `expect(element('input[id="myInput"] + div.tooltip').count()).toBe(/* 0(no focus) or 1(focus) */)` Quite hacky :-(, but working at least.

Comment: This look promising: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5318415/which-browsers-support-document-activeelement Maybe there's a way to add a new matcher that uses an element and document.activeElement.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Testing for focus an AngularJS directive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18850219/testing-for-focus-an-angularjs-directive)

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/18850219/135114, the `toHaveFocus` solution offered there seems to be working great for me (angular 1.0.7, latest karma running latest Chrome)

Answer (score 1):

I see two options here. The first, which I really recommend, specially on E2E tests, is to use [Jasmine-jQuery](https://github.com/velesin/jasmine-jquery) which provides the `toBeFocused` matcher which deals with this.

If you don't want to include Jasmine-jQuery because it's too big or because you don't like it, then you have two options:

- Compare the button with the document's active element, can access it with: `document.activeElement`
- Compare the button with the document's active element by getting it from the element itself (this is the way jasmine-jquery does it) with: `DOMELEMENT.ownerDocument.activeElement`

Comment: I'm completely new to angular. As I wanted to implement the first alternative you provided, I got confused since : `detailLib.getFieldInput('inputId')` returns an `ElementFinder` while `document.activeElement` returns an Element. So I can't just assert they're equal like `expect(detailLib.getFieldInput('InputId').equals(document.activeElement);`. What am I doing wrong ?