# Testing for focus an AngularJS directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, jasmine, karma-runner

How can you test for focus in an AngularJS directive? I would expect the following to work:

```
describe('focus test', function(){
    it('should focus element', function(){
        var element = $('<input type="text" />');
        // Append to body because otherwise it can't be foccused
        element.appendTo(document.body);
        element.focus();
        expect(element.is(':focus')).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

However, this only works in IE, it fails in Firefox and Chrome

Update:
The solution by @S McCrohan works. Using this I created a 'toHaveFocus' matcher:

```
beforeEach(function(){
    this.addMatchers({
        toHaveFocus: function(){
            this.message = function(){
                return 'Expected \'' + angular.mock.dump(this.actual) + '\' to have focus';
            };

            return document.activeElement === this.actual[0];
        }
    });
});
```

Which is used as follows:

```
expect(myElement).toHaveFocus();
```

Note that for focus related tests, the compiled element has to be attached to the DOM, which can be done like this:

```
myElement.appendTo(document.body);
```

Comment: Hello Mark, could it be that this solution is somehow flawed? I have noticed that whatever I append to the DOM in my test, that will automatically be seen as the "document.activeElement". So it does not really seem to test if it is indeed focused?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try `'document.activeElement'` instead of `':focus'`. I haven't tested it in karma, but `$('document.activeElement')` behaves as desired under standard jQuery.

Answer (score 7):

In Jasmine 2, this is now:

```
beforeEach(function() {
  jasmine.addMatchers({
    toHaveFocus: function() {
      return {
        compare: function(actual) {
          return {
            pass: document.activeElement === actual[0]
          };
        }
      };
    }
  });
});
```