# Karma Test Cases : focus event

Tags: angularjs, focus, karma-runner

I am testing a focus event in angularjs using karma test cases. But the element is not getting focused. Right after I do **element.focus()** and check if the element 
is focused, I get false. And **document.activeElement** at that point is the whole body.

Please suggest a solution. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

(This answer inspired by [Testing for focus an AngularJS directive](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18850219/135114))

You need to add your element to the document body in order for *document.activeElement* to play with it.

Before you call `element.focus()`, do this:

```
element.appendTo(document.body);
```

Also, if you're doing this in unit tests I would recommend that you remove the element after the test, otherwise each test will add another element to the body (and it could affect your other tests' results).

```
afterEach(function () {
    element.remove();
}
```

Comment: This worked for me (mostly).  I'm not using JQuery, so `element.appendTo` didn't cut it.  I needed to do `document.body.appendChild(element[0]);`