# Mocha / Karma - how to test CSS properties

Tags: unit-testing, mocha.js, karma-mocha

The angular directive that I am responsible for testing manipulates much of the css with click handlers.  Also, it adds the css styles inside of the element.

```
 angular.element(dropDown).css({display: 'block'});
```

I have referenced another stack overflow post [Testing whether certain elements are visible or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16022180/testing-whether-certain-elements-are-visible-or-not)

I changed **toBe to .to.be**  for mocha.  I also tried to check for a attribute to be added on the click.  Here are my expects listed below.

```
expect(elem('.dropdown-menu').css('display')).to.be('none');
expect(elem.getAttribute('display')).to.be('block');
```

However, I am getting

```
[[object HTMLUListElement]]' is not a function 
TypeError: elem.getAttribute is not a function
```

I know it would be easier not have the css in the directive like so, but am wondering if anyone has tested for this or knows how to debug these?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### What is `elem` in the context of your spec? Is that the `$compiled` directive?

#### What does your `beforeEach` look like?

#### What does the internal implementation of `dropDown` look like?

---

This is how I test my directives:

```
describe('directive', function () {
  var el, $scope; 

  beforeEach(function () {
    module('my.mod');

    inject(function ($compile, $rootScope) {
      $scope = $rootScope.$new();
      el     = $compile('<some-custom-dir></some-custom-dir>')($scope);

      $scope.$digest();
      // or if isolated $scope: 
      el.isolateScope().$digest();
    });
  });

  it('some css property', function () {
    expect(el.css('display')).to.eq('block');
  });

  it('some attribute', function () {
    expect(el[0].getAttribute('something')); // You need to unwrap the angular.element(el) with [0] to access the native methods. 
  });

  it('some other attribute', function () {
    expect(el.attr('someAttr')).to.eq('...'); // Or just use .attr()
  });
});
```

---

Also, `to.be` **cannot** be used that way. 
You can use `to.be` in the following ways:

```
.to.be.true; 
.to.be.false;
.to.be.null;
.to.be.undefined;
.to.be.empty;
.to.be.arguments;
.to.be.ok;
.to.be.above();
.to.be.a(Type);
.to.be.an(Type);
.to.be.closeTo(min, max); // delta range
.to.be.instanceOf(Constructor);
.to.be.within(min, max);
.to.be.at.most(max);
.to.be.below(max);
.to.be.at.least(min);
.to.be.above(min);
```

What you are looking for is the `.to.eq` or `.to.equal` method.

```
expect('asdf').to.be('asdf'); // Nope!
expect('qwer').to.eq('qwer'); // Yay!

expect([]).to.eq([]);         // Nope..
expect([]).to.deep.equal([]); // Yay!

expect({}).to.eq({});  // Nope..
expect({}).to.eql({}); // Yay!
```

Comment: this shows me TypeError: expect(...).to is undefined